# How to dual boot with a live image

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Sorry if this has already been asked but I can't find it.
I have a lack of different storage devices available to me, and I need to install Ubuntu, but due to my lack of devices I have no spare USBs or hard drives that will work, and a mini CD doesn't work for me. I do have an external hard drive that has the live image, however, it also has a running copy of Linux on it, so how do I boot to the live image instead of the full copy?

Answer (score 0):

Writing a live image to the HDD destroys your boot partition. If you can boot into the "running copy of linux" in the HDD, it means that the live image is not installed onto the HDD. I dont think there is a way to do this. You need to get a CD/USB from somewhere.

Thank You.

Comment: If you have grub2, you can directly boot ISO. Drive, partition and path is critical and is as seen before Ubuntu is mounted, so no /home etc. ISO Booting with Grub 2 from Hard drive - drs305
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot
Examples - you may copy & edit for your path & ISO version
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549847

Answer (score 0):

Please find a USB drive and install the image file using [Unetbootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/)
Now you could restart your system and make sure the GRUB menu is appearing properly.